# Celery appears to be ack-ing a seg-faulting worker

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I've written a test for my celery code. The worker is configured so that acks_late is set to True. I have a special function that intentionally seg-faults the code, based on https://wiki.python.org/moin/CrashingPython:

```
def crash():
    """
    crash the Python interpreter...
    """
    import ctypes
    i = ctypes.c_char('a')
    j = ctypes.pointer(i)
    c = 0
    while True:
            j[c] = 'a'
            c += 1
    j
```

My task does simply a time.sleep(10) followed by a call to crash().

If I...

- Kill the main worker process prior to killing the child workers, then the task appears in the queue again, ready to be picked up.
- Kill the child worker (sig 9) or cause it to crash via a seg-fault (sig 11), the task disappears from the rabbitMQ queue. My guess is that its being acked by the parent task. You can see in the logs that it raises a WorkerLostError.

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this before and knows of a workaround or fix. Thanks!